# Java: Store specific part of string to an array

Tags: java, regex, shell

I'm using inputstreamer to retrieve the output of a shell command running continuously providing an output.

I've managed to isolate a part of the shell output by printing it here: `System.out.println(inputStr.substring(inputStr.lastIndexOf(" ")+1));`

However, I'd like to store the output in either of two arrrays, depending on the expression of the shell output.

Say we have two shell outpust that follows this syntax: `IP 192.168.0.12.4588 > 212.98.120.24.443 psx 4488` as the first one, and the opposite: `IP 212.98.120.24.443 > 192.168.0.12.4588 psx 12`

From the above print, I can isolate and print both `4488` as well as `12`. But if 192.168.0.x.x is the first IP, the value `4448` to be stored in a specific array. Likewise, if > 192.168.0.x.x is on the other side, I want to store the value `12` in a different array.

How would I go about that?

Comment: You could use `regex`...

Comment: I'm reading up on regex now. How would you use regex to distinguish which side of `>` 192.168.0.XX.XXX is on? xx.xxx can change at any given time. only 192.168.0 is constant :)

Comment: You can parse the whole input for an object like (ip, left_side, right_side,psx, number) and then compare if your left side starts with 192.168.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String temp = "IP 212.98.120.24.443 > 192.168.0.12.4588 psx 12";
    if(temp.matches(".*192\\.168\\.0\\..*>.*"))
    {
        System.out.println("1st");
        //your code here
    }
    else if(temp.matches(".*>.*192\\.168\\.0\\..*"))
    {
        System.out.println("2nd");
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I was also succesful with `tmp.matches(".*?192\\.168\\.0\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\s*>.*?")` -> left. and `tmp.matches(".*?>\\s*192\\.168\\.0\\.\\d+\\.\\d+.*?")` -> right.

Comment: Very helpful! As written above the values might change after 192.168.0, but I think you worked around that. Giving it a shot, cheers